# What is the real value of Collections.synchronizedList/synchronizedMap?

Tags: java, multithreading

I don't see any real value of using Collections.synchronizedList/synchronizedMap, and further more as per documentation we need to synchronize list/map during iteration, which is not good for performance.

I can just use ConcurrentMap/CopyOnWriteArrayList class. Basically I'm asking in what case we only need to use Collections.synchronizedList/synchronizedMap rather than utilize classes in java.util.concurrent package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't see any real value of using Collections.synchronizedList/synchronizedMap, and further more as per documentation we need to synchronize list/map during iteration, which is not good for performance.

Iterating over a collection is not a good idea for performance regardless.  You should be building your structures so they don't need to be iterated over, if you care about performance.

> I can just use ConcurrentMap/CopyOnWriteArrayList class. Basically I'm asking in what case we only need to use Collections.synchronizedList/synchronizedMap rather than utilize classes in java.util.concurrent package.

The concurrent collections are often simpler to use.  You should note that a small ConcurrentHashMap will be many times larger than a synchronised HashMap, so unless you only have a few of them HashMap still may be the best option.

CopyOnWriteArrayList is very fast for reads, but very expensive for updates. (It copies the entire array on an add or remove, possibly more than once)

Comment: hey iterating over a collection is almost happen in most of the cases. but then still on what case i should only use synchronizeList/Map rather than concurrent collections ? when you said is ConcurrentHashMap is larger than sync HashMap ? what do you mean?

Comment: By larger, I mean it uses much more memory. If you have to worry about memory usage, you might use HashMap instead.  If you have lots of writes, a synchronized list is better.

Comment: @Adelave If you are iterating over a collection like a synchronized Map often, you have a problem with your code, or you are not worried about performance.